# How to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error?

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm creating a method that will accept some values from a user and send them to a stored procedure in SQL server.Couple days ago the code was working fine now I'm getting these error that I don't know how to handle.This came up after I run the code 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' when I click on at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) it states that the source attachment doesn't contain the source for Class.class and finally the other error I see takes me back to a line in the code

```
void addcustomer(int trn,String Lname,String Fname,String Mname,String Mstatus, String Dob,String Email,String tel,String PA,String MA,String Eng_num, int Emp_id,String dateP,String PartO)
   {
         String ConnectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"+"databaseName=car_inventory;integratedSecurity=true;"; //creating a connection string

          // Declare the JDBC objects
          Connection Conn=null;
          Statement stmt=null;
          ResultSet rs=null;

          try
          {
              //establish connection
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              Conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dbase2");/*This is the line where the last error points to*/

              CallableStatement sp = Conn.prepareCall("{call    addcustomer(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
               sp.setInt(1,trn);
                sp.setString(2,Lname);
                sp.setString(3,Fname);
                sp.setString(4,Mname);
                sp.setString(5,Mstatus);
                sp.setString(6,Dob);
                sp.setString(7,Email);
                sp.setString(8,tel);
                sp.setString(9,PA);
                sp.setString(10,MA);
                sp.setString(11,Eng_num);
                sp.setInt(12,Emp_id);
                sp.setString(13,dateP);
                sp.setString(14,PartO);
          }//end of try

          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }//end of catch

          finally
          {
              if (rs != null) 
                    try 
                { 
                        rs.close(); 
                } 
                catch(Exception e) 
                {

                }
                if (stmt != null)
                    try 
                { 
                    stmt.close();
                } 
                catch(Exception e) 
                {

                }
                if (Conn != null) 
                    try 
                {
                        Conn.close(); 
                }
                catch(Exception e) 
                {

                }

          }//end of finally      

   }//end of addcustomer
```

Comment: Not having the source code avvailable is not the same as getting a `ClassNotFoundException` exception. If solving the exception is your main goal, you should edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you do not have the driver in your classpath please check that?

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException is thrown when JVM tries to load a class and that class is not available in the classpath